Flutter Android: How to bundle custom action icon for release build?
I built an android app with custom icons in the notification.
Running it in debug mode works fine, but when I install it in release mode the custom icons don't show up.
How can I configure flutter to bundle custom icons so they get included in the right path in the app bundle, so that audio-service can load them?
So far I have manually included them in android/app/src/main/res/drawable:
Image: Project Directory Structure
Image: Notification with and without icons
Code:
  static MediaControl like = MediaControl.custom(
    androidIcon: 'drawable/up',
    label: 'Like',
    name: 'like',
  );

  static MediaControl dislike = MediaControl.custom(
    androidIcon: 'drawable/down',
    label: 'Dislike',
    name: 'dislike'
  );

  static MediaControl oneStar = MediaControl.custom(
    androidIcon: 'drawable/one',
    label: 'Star',
    name: 'star'
  );

My repo with the bug: https://github.com/chrisheib/musicapp

So far I found out: in debug build the files get placed into the apk (which is just a zip file and readable as such once the extension is changed) into the res directory.
In release mode the aapt mechanism repacks all resource files, gives them abstract file names and keeps track of the original ids.

Some of the ids work in both release and debug: 'drawable/two.xml' is correctly packed and also found in release mode. None of the other 8 files are packed correcly.

The problem seems to be the id resolution and not the file content, as once swapped the file content of a file thats not openable in release mode is rendered correctly with the previously working id.

Adding shrinkResources = false to android - buildTypes - relase in android/app/build.grade works!!!
